# Meaning of 味を増した

Tags: meaning, expressions, manga, comparative-constructions

What is the meaning of 味を増した in the following sentence? Context: Two boxers meet after a long time, but Boxer A isn't in a good mood because is worried about his imminent qualifying match. So Boxer B has the following thoughts (I divided the sentence as it is in the manga):

> せっかくの再会なのに残念 / そんなに思い詰める程ヤバイ相手なんだ… / より　**味を増した**キミでも？

My rough translation of it would be `What a shame, now that we met again. Did he get an opponent even stronger than him?`, but I don't understand the exact meaning of 味を増した. I am also not sure about より being a comparative there, it is strangely placed in the sentence and there's a little space after it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fermented food like *natto*, *miso* and *cheese* will gain stronger taste and smell over time. 味が増す (literally "taste increases") figuratively refers to this phenomenon. It means to grow old but experienced and mature as a veteran. より is simply "more" here (see: [Use of より in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48962/5010)). For example 年齢を重ねてより味が増した俳優 refers to a good-looking middle-aged actor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So it could be translated as "Is he worried because he got a strong opponent more experienced even than him?" ?

Comment: @Marco 味を増した modifies キミ. "Even an experienced veteran boxer like you are worried?"

Comment: And what does より modify? 味を増した? "a more experienced boxer"?

Comment: Yes, it directly modifies 味を増した (literally "taste increased *more*")

Answer (score 0):

> ..ヤバイ相手なんだ… / より　味を増したキミでも？
>
> it is strangely placed in the sentence and there's a little space after it.

I think almost all naruto's answer is correct except for the interpretation of the space.
I think the space is inevitable to be read smoothly as the intended meaning.

I'll show you the reason.

"より *more*" is natural to be used when comparing A and B.
For example A is "前/以前のキミ" and B is "今のキミ".

Though the given phrase seems almost meaningful, some words are omitted.
If you write it as a complete phrase it would become like:

> 1. / **以前**より味を増した**今の**キミでも？

In this case, no space is needed after "より".

If you omit 今 from sentence 1, you will get sentence 2, which is almost the same meaning as sentence 1.

> 2. / **以前**より味を増したキミでも？

No space is required also in this phrase.

Let's examine the given phrase.
If you omit the space from it, it will become as:

> 3. / より味を増したキミでも？

Readers might get confused in reading this phrase.
"yorimiを"? "yoriajiを"? What does "より味" mean?

So, the space is inevitable in this abbreviated phrase.