# Function of より before a noun in a phrase

Tags: grammar, particle-より

I came across this sentence/fragment from a song:

誰かの演技を真似してみて　より自分が分かったり

I'm having trouble what the function of the より before the noun is supposed to be doing. Is より自分 a set phrase that doesn't appear in the dictionary? Is there another function of より besides being a comparative particle and meaning "more" as an adverb in front of adjectives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This より is an **adverb**, and it's modifying 分かる, not 自分. When you encounter an adverb you have to find the next adjective or verb. For example, in とても歌が上手い ("One is very good at singing"), とても is modifying the next i-adjective 上手い. より分かる means "understand *better*" or "know *more*". より自分が分かる (or 自分がより分かる) means "to understand myself better".

See also:

- [Use of より in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48962/5010)

Comment: Thanks! Considering I already knew that adverbs and modifiers can be placed anytime before a verb(kinda), now I feel dumb for not seeing before that it was just modifying the verb lol. Sometimes I guess my brain just switches itself off for a moment.